# How to change default UWP apps installation folder

Tags: uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am using PowerShell to install UWP app on a Windows10 machine. It is installing in "WindowsApps" folder.

Is it possible to choose another folder to install(SideLoad) UWP apps using PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see: https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/change-install-location-windows-10-apps/

there is no argument you can pass with the powershell. It's a system setting

Comment: Thanks for your reply